# how to let user define their own plugins under the scope and make it visible to himself?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using the flask to built a web app ,it hold all the input message(user send it the xml message) and find the right plugin to response  and return the response to user, the app had provided the basic plugins, but i want the user to write their own plugins under the my defined apis, below is the architecture:

```
plugins     
   common_plugins1.py
   common_plugins2.py  
templates   
actions   
myapp.py
```

but i faced several problems:

1. i only want the user call his plugin not others and other plugins is invisible to him
2. i only want the user call the defined functions or modules i defined
3. i want to make it scalable

if is it possible to let the user upload their plugins write by python? and make the app dynamically load it.

thanks for your help!

below is the plugin example:

```
#coding: utf-8
import somemodule 
from somemodule import *

def do(dmessage,context,default,**option):
    import re   
    try:
        _l=default.split('%|placeholder|%')
        message=ModuleRequestVoice(dmessage)
        r=ModuleResponseMusic()
        return r.render(message,_l[0],_l[1],_l[2],_l[2])
    except Exception,e:
        print 'match voice error:%s'%e
        return False
```

Comment: You are going to allow users to upload any python file which will be executed on your server inside your application whicn is run by your user? It is suicide

Comment: @Tigra yes, when i actually make a plan , i found >_<, so i wonder if there any ways to make it possible to let them write plugins?write a DSL for them?